# (rpi) linux how to kill a process (PiAUISuite) or find the file where the pid is written

Tags: raspberry-pi, pid, kill-process

I am using a program (PiAUISuite, http://stevenhickson.blogspot.com.es/) that I cannot find how to kill the process. Looking at the code (https://github.com/StevenHickson/PiAUISuite) I can see that it checks if the pid_file is empty or not, so it definitively employs it but I cannot find where is the file. Once the program is running, there's nothing in /var/run (at least that I can see).

Then the question is, how to properly kill a process in linux (raspberry pi, raspbian)  when you don't know if the program offers such funcionality. And if you want to kill it through the PID, how to find where the PID_FILE is, provided that it seems that the program uses one?

Answer (score 0):

I use 'sudo killall voicecommand'